# how to get working directory during NUNIT init?

Tags: initialization, nunit, init, working-directory

here is a tricky one:

- I have a unit test `Test(string value)` that must be called several times with different
  parameter values.
- The list of values to be provided are read from another method `GetValues()` that is specified in the `[Test]` attribute of `Test()`
- `GetValues()` must read the content of a file `Values.txt` in the working directory to return the values
- the working directory is **not** the test assembly directory

In order to achieve this, I need to know the working directory when `GetValues()` is called, but I can't find this inforrmation because:

- `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the directory of the assembly, not the working directory where nunit is called from,
- `TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkingDirectory` is not yet defined, and results in a `System.NullReferenceException`

I also tried to load the content of the file during the fixture setup but this is called after `GetValues()`, so no luck: I can find the file but the null pointer exception was already raised.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you in advance for your help

Cedric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could read, this feature will not be available until vestion 3.0, when the working directory should simply not change.